# Failed to load control 'user control name' from

Tags: vb6

Failed to load control 'user contol name' from . Your version of may be outdated. Make sure you are using the version of the control that was provided with your application
i have read this document

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942870

but since it is is a internal contol added to the project itself i don't think this will be helpful for me

please suggest me the probable cause of the error

please note the blank after 'from' and 'of' in the error...

I have searched for those with similar problems, but 
most people have this problem when they are working with compiled 
ocxs and replacing  .ocx files. fixes their error.but  in my 
case, with user controls, I am not sure of which files must be 
replaced in order to correct the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your project contains both your form and your usercontrol, then you may be referencing a compiled version of your control without realizing it.  Have a look at your component references and see.

Comment: thanks for your reply and sorry for the late response but you please elaborate what you meant(what i need to check)..

Answer (score 1):

The question is very general so I am giving a general answer.

In your project folder should be a NameOfYourForm.log file with information what could not be loaded. Also look to the .frm file in text editor (Notepad) and at the begining of the file is a list of included components with versions. From those information you can find which versions of which component you need. Alternatively you add those information to your question or create a new one.